# How do I create a Button when I click another Button?

Tags: unity, c#

I need help. When I click a Button, I want to create a new Button. My code, however, creates four Buttons. What should I do?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AddButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabButton;
    public RectTransform ParentPanel;
    public Button saveButton;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
           // for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton) as GameObject;
                button.transform.SetParent(ParentPanel, false);
                button.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
             }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Input.GetMouseButton(0)` will return true during every frame where you keep holding the button. Unity frames are quite fast, so it requires quite a lot of agility to hold a button for just one frame.

Try `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` instead. It only returns `true` during the first update of a click.

By the way: Your code will spawn a new button no matter where you click, because it just detects mouse clicks, not where these clicks happen. If you want an event to happen when a button is clicked, you shouldn't use the Input class. Add a method as an event handler for that button, instead. You can do that [in the editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/script-Button.html) or [with a script](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html).